# Values does not change between ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="" class="names" id="1">Name 1</a>
    <a href="" class="names" id="2">Name 2</a>
    <a href="" class="names" id="3">Name 3</a>
    <br/><br/>
    <button id="btn1">BTN1</button>
    <button id="btn2">BTN2</button>

    <div id="content"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.names').click(function(e){
            var name = $(this).attr('id');
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#btn1').click(function(e){
                var btn = $(this).attr('id');
                alert('Name = '+name+' btn='+btn);
                e.preventDefault();
            });
            $('#btn2').click(function(e){
                var btn = $(this).attr('id');
                alert('Name = '+name+' btn='+btn);
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In my project, all the stuff is happening with the help of ajax.

So when, let's say, Name 3 is clicked, and then BTN1 is clicked, the alert contains "Name = 3 btn = btn1".

After this, if I click Name 1, and I click BTN2, then the first alert contains "Name = 3 btn = btn2", and the second alert contains "Name = 1 btn = btn2".

I think this is the default behavior. But what I need to happen is as follows:

- if I click Name 3 and BTN2, then the alert to display "Name = 3 btn = btn2"
- then, if I click Name 1 and BTN1, then the alert to display "Name = 1 btn = btn1"
- then, if I click Name 2 and BTN2, then the alert to display "Name = 2 btn = btn2"
- etc

So each and every time I click on a different name (and then no matter what btn), the alert to display the name and btn accordingly.

Is there any way to do that? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI, binding event withing event callback is a BAD practice. for example:

```
   $('.names').click(function () {
     $('button[id^=btn]').click(function () {
        // code
     });
   });
```

What is happening on above code is, a `click` event to `button[id^=btn]` is binding every time you're clicking on `.names`.

Solution:

```
var name, btn;

function do_alert() {
   name && btn && alert('Name = ' + name + ' btn=' + btn);
   name = btn = null;
}

$('.names').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    name = $(this).attr('id');
});

$('button[id^=btn]').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    btn = $(this).attr('id');
    do_alert();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vm0yd9dq/1/)

Comment: Thanks for you time. Can you provide some useful links to read more about this?